# Unix - CSV to Oracle db data issue

Tags: bash, unix, ms-access, csv, export-to-csv

I'm importing long numbers from CSV into an Oracle database using sqlplus through Unix.

I have numbers

```
55000000024    55000000017
```

On import into the database they show as

```
5.5E+11    5.5E+11
```

Can anyone suggest a way that I can import the full number please?

This Unix code creates the sql statement from the csv.

```
    cat $1 > po.lis

while read filename; do
insertval=$(echo $filename | sed "s/*//g;s/,/','/g;s/^/'/;s/$/'/")
echo $insertval > $1

cat *.csv | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/^\(.*\)$/INSERT INTO USER.TMP_STYPO_IMPORT(L_BF_MAT_CHAR_VAL,L_EST_FCOST,L_EST_LCOST,L_SEASON,L_STY_NUM,L_STY_QUAL,L_STY_NAME,L_STY_TYPE,L_COMP_DIV,L_STY_RET_TYPE,L_STY_PDT_TYPE,L_PDT_CATEGORY,L_FS_GROUP,L_STY_CONTENT,L_STORAGE_TYPE,L_CON_NUM,L_CON,L_VAT_TYPE,L_BUY_OFFICE,L_PACK_TYPE,L_STY_TPRICE,L_STY_WEIGHT,L_STY_BARCODE1,L_STY_BARCODE2,L_STY_BARCODE3,L_STY_BARCODE4,L_STY_BARCODE5,L_STY_BARCODE6,L_STY_BARCODE7,L_STY_BARCODE8,L_STY_BARCODE9,L_STY_BARCODE10,L_STY_BARCODE11,L_STY_BARCODE12,L_UNIT_BARCODE_FMT,L_CUST_REF,L_PODATE,L_POQTY1,L_POQTY2,L_POQTY3,L_POQTY4,L_POQTY5,L_POQTY6,L_POQTY7,L_POQTY8,L_POQTY9,L_POQTY10,L_POQTY11,L_POQTY12,PO_WRK_UNIT_NUM,P_LSTY_SIZE,P_STY_COMP,P_COMP_EST_RATIO,P_COMP_EST_RATE,P_MAT_NUM,P_MONEY_SYMBOL,P_MONEY_RATE,P_COST_CODE,P_EST_MONEY_RATE,P_STY_STATE,P_MF_GROUP,P_SHIP_TYPE,P_MAIL_ORDER,P_PACK_PRODUCT,P_PACK_SOLID,P_UNIT_EAN_CHECK,P_PACK_EAN_CHECK,P_EGIFT_CARD,P_INCLUDE_IN_PROMOTIONS,P_SCAN_ENABLED,P_CARTON_TYPE,P_PACK_BARCODE_FMT,P_STOCK_KEEPING_PACK,P_PRICE_LIST,P_ACTIVE,P_STY_SIZE,P_PDT_CATEGORY) VALUES(\1);/' > $1.sql
```

This is imported using;

```
    ORACLE_HOME=/###/###
export ORACLE_HOME
ORACLE_SID=#
export ORACLE_###

rm /###/###/stypo.log

rundir="/###/###/Import_Test/*csv.sql"
ls -1 $rundir > sqltorun.list

while read p; do

$ORACLE_HOME/###/sqlplus user/pswrd @./###/###/Import_Test/$p << EOF >> /###/###/stypo.log
exit
EOF

done < sqltorun.list
```

Thanks,

Comment: What datatype is the column?

Comment: It's a VARCHAR datatype, with that, it seems embarrassingly obvious to try altering that to NUMBER.

Comment: Hmm, strange that it would be converted to scientific notation then (unless bash is more clever than I realised). And they are definitely like '55000000024' in the raw csv? Apps like Excel will often display number normally but then could covert to scientific notation when you export as csv.

Comment: Apologies. The file has been exported from an Access system and sent to me as a csv file. When I view the csv in Unix, it displays 5.5E+11. Altering the datatype to number was helpful, but it displays 55000000000 instead of 550000024. Is there something extra I need to do to the file before the import work?

Comment: you'll have to rexport from access with some extra care about defining the output columns format. Sorry been years since I've done this, so I can't advise. This is now an Access question. Best to reframe and repost with an Access tag. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

5.5E+11 = 55000000000 so if that's what is in the CSV, the export process has lost some precision. Obviously there's no way for SQL to work out that there's a 24 missing. Whoever does the export from Access would need to look at that.